# How to first use javascript to validate form data before triggering onServerClick for HTML Input button?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

So right now it all looks pretty with ...

```
<button type="submit" runat="server" name="subscribe" id="Button1" class="link-button" onserverclick="saveListing">
```

Until it is time to validate the data before calling saveListing function codebehind (in VB .Net).

How can true/false be return so that when true saveListing will be called, otherwise not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add `onclick='if(! validateFunction()) return false;`.

I can't recall correctly whether HTML button control had onclicentclick property. Surely, if the web control `<asp:Button  ...` it has a property `OnClientClick` where you can give the same value above for this effect as well.